# Angular ngFor else template displayed multiple times

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi I've got an template

```
                            <ol class="lmn-list-group lmn-list-group-initial">
                                <ng-container *ngFor="let value of group.values">
                                    <ng-container *ngIf="value.crId; else crCreationFailTmp">
                                        <li class="lmn-list-group-item">
                                            <a [href]="value.crUrl" target="_blank" [mtTooltip]="value.crId" placement="top">
                                                {{ 'CR IN ' + value.crId }}
                                            </a>
                                            <div class="lmn-pb-2 bfaText">{{ value.name }}</div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ng-container>
                                </ng-container>
                            </ol>

                <ng-template #crCreationFailTmp>
                    <p class="lmn-pl-3 lmn-text-danger">Change request creation failed</p>
               </ng-template>
```

Hi my `crCreationFailTmp` is been displayed multiple times. I want it to display once when `else` block is executed. How will i get `value.crId` if I try to execute `ngIf` before `ngFor`?

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you want to display this "else" message even if only one item is missing the id, so you can try to separate it from the `ngIf` , something like this :

```
<p *ngIf="group.values.find(value => !value.crId)?.length" 
   class="lmn-pl-3 lmn-text-danger">Change request creation failed
</p>
```

means - even if one of the list is missing the `crId` you display this message